# jqplot line chart repeating x-axis value

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using JQ -Plot line chart for creating a dashbord. But i have a problem repeating the date values in x-axis. how can i remove repeated date values?

[image]

Here i want to show only first july 10 and jul 11

Comment: i had the very same issue. I found out it is a bug in jqplot. By specifying the number of ticks (eg: numberTicks: data.length) it was solved. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You have several things you can do in order to remove repeated date values :

- specify your own ticks using `axes: {xaxis: {ticks: ['Jul 10', 'Jul 11'] }}`,
- specify the number of ticks you want using `axes: {xaxis: {numberTicks: 2}}` (you can in addition specify the min value and/or the max value),
- specify the gap between two ticks using `axes: {xaxis: {tickInterval: '1 day', min: 'July 10, 2014}}

Don't hesitate to create a jsfiddle with your code in order to exchange words about it.